# Scala, Quill - how to compare values with case-insensitive?

Tags: scala, quill

I created a `quill` query, which should find some data in database by given parameter:

```
val toFind = "SomeName"
val query = query.find(value => infix"$value = ${lift(toFind)}".as[Boolean])
```

It works fine when for example I have data in database "SomeName", but if I want to have same results by passing there "somename" I found nothing. The problem is with data case-sensitive.
Is it possible to always find values with case-insensitive way? In `quill` docs I have not found anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. It is enough to add `LOWER()` sql function to `infix`:

```
val query = query.find(value => infix"LOWER($value) = ${lift(toFind.toLowerCase)}".as[Boolean])
```